# How to send a list of embedded URLs to a second parse scrapy function?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
def parse(self, response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    for a in soup.find_all("a", "_119e1b", href=True):
        game_url = ((a["href"]))
        yield scrapy.Request(game_url, callback=self.parsenestedgame)

def parsenestedgame(self, response):

    nested_url = response.url
    print(nested_url+"Hello")
```

I just started to switch my Bs4 script over to Scrapy and am brand new to Scrapy but I see where it can add a lot of value for me at scrapinghub.com so I don't know much.  I am scraping a list of URLs which are parsed for another list of URLS.  How can I send this list of URLs over to the second parse function?  I have looked for a solution for awhile but can't seem to find one.  Once it hits the first embedded URL it gives `2020-06-09 20:57:39 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to "URL" GET "embedded URL">` Then it goes back to the next URL in the top list of URLs but never actually uses the second parse function.  How can I fix this? I have been trying to figure it out for awhile.

Comment: it seems you get urls to external pages - but `Scrapy` as default don't scrape external pages - you have it in message `"Filtered offsite request to "URL" GET "embedded URL"`. You may have to add external domains to `allowed_domains = [...]` or try empty list `allowed_domains = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a spider skeleton using

```
scrapy genspider example example.com/test
```

You will these two lines

```
  allowed_domains = ['example.com']
  start_urls = ['http://example.com/test/']
```

In your case, you would need to check allowed_domains. Note that it is a list of string. Looks like your spider is following links that are going out of the allowed domains.

Simply add the desired domains to `allowed_domains` list. Note that while setting it to `None` would also work but it is a dangerous practice. Things can get pretty nasty and spider can run forever.

Comment: I did change it to `allowed_domains = []` and it worked.  But before my allow_domains variable was just a subset of what domains I would expect to see.  For example, my allowed domain was google.com when the scraper would try to follow external links to google.com/cat it wouldn't work.  I can't specifically choose the allowed domains verbatim because these are dynamically generated by the website I am scraping every day.

Answer (score 0):

OffsiteMiddleware  filters out every request whose host names aren’t in the spider’s allowed_domains attribute. so you cant set `allowed_domains =None` to avoid  it

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue of sending the extracted urls to the next functions you can use meta.

```
yield scrapy.Request(req_url, callback = self.function_name, meta = {'urls':URL_list})
```